# Google Charts: baseline not working with mirrorlog

Tags: charts, google-visualization, baseline

I'm trying to create a chart using mirrorlog scale, and it seems to be ignoring the baseline; bars always start from 0.

```
function drawChart1() {
        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['', 'val', { role: 'style' }],
          [' ', 0.6, 'red'],


        ]);

        ops = {

            height: 50,
            hAxis: {
                ticks: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.65, 1.0],
                baseline: 0.3,
                textPosition: 'out',
                scaleType: 'mirrorLog',
            },
            chartArea: { height: '20%', backgroundColor: 'yellow', top: 3 },
            fontSize: 8,
            legend: { position: 'none' },
            bar: { groupWidth: "15%" },
            axes: {
                y: {
                    0: { position: 'none' }
                }
            }
        };
        chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, ops);
    }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ItalianPete/p5w887pz/)

Comment: Changing the `baseline` seems to move a black bar on the graph:  https://imgur.com/a/jOcXYDF. Try removing 0.1 and 0.2 from `ticks`:  `ticks: [0.3, 0.65, 1.0]` and the chart starts at 0.3.